# Passing object type in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to achieve this, no idea if it feasible though..
Here is a code sample:

```
public List<Tuple<AbstractPlateforme, AbstractPlateforme>> tuple;
Type type1 = tuple.Item1.GetType();
//This line gives me error: Error   CS0118  'type1' is a variable but is used like a type
var plateforme = PlateformeHelper.GetPlateforme<type1>();

//This is my method from my PlateformeHelper class which returns an instance of an instantiated object of the same type (the list may only contain 1 object of that type which inherit from AbstractPlateforme)
public static T GetPlateforme<T>() where T : AbstractPlateforme
{
    return (T)ListePlateforme.Find(x => x.GetType() == typeof (T));
}
```

Comment: Too abstract, what are you trying to achieve? Why does `ListePlateforme` store different types at all?

Comment: I need to store different types of AbstractPlateforme child's so I can get specific information for each class and access them from other class.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, fix it first: tuple in line1 is a List and a List do not have Item1 in line2.

Comment: @mecek I have a list of tuple and in my tuple I have 2 items

Comment: tuple is not a Tuple in your code, it is a List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an overload that accepts a `Type` parameter instead of being generic:

```
public static AbstractPlateforme GetPlateforme(Type type)
{
    return (AbstractPlateforme)ListePlateforme.Find(x => x.GetType() == type);
}

public static T GetPlateforme<T>() where T : AbstractPlateforme
{
    return (T)GetPlateforme(typeof(T));
}
```

Then you can simply call the new overload instead:

```
var plateforme = PlateformeHelper.GetPlateforme(type1);
```

Comment: Only thing I would add is that since the non-generic method returns an `object` a cast would be necessary after the call.

Comment: Yeah, well, if he has the type and can cast to it, he could also call the generic version. You can only cast to an actual type, you cannot easily, without using reflection, cast to a type held in a variable or expression, if that is even necessary. If you haven't written code that relines on the type being of type X, then most likely you're not taking advantage of whatever X provides anyway, or he would have to write the calling code as generic as well.

Comment: Agreed - mixing reflection and generics is a pain in most cases, let alone when casting is involved.  I like your edit better then casting on the client side.  +1

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use reflection with generics, maybe it will help you see the code bellow:

```
    Type type1 = tuple.Item1.GetType();    
    MethodInfo method = typeof(PlateformeHelper).GetMethod("GetPlateforme");
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type1);
    generic.Invoke(null, null);
```

For more info [MakeGenericMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx)

Hope be useful XD.